# questions about choosing suitable data structure in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, data-structures, hashmap

My problem is that there are 3 variables, say a,b,c

First, information a,b,c needed to be input and stored.

For example a=Tom, b=school A, c=1402

Then, I can get the above information by entering "Tom", in this case, if there is another Tom in school B，that message would also be printed out.

or by entering "Tom, school A", then only that Tom would be printed out. In this problem, their would be no duplicates if a and b are both locked.

Well, my view is that a must be a key, and a+b can be a composite key. So firstly I thought of a HashMap, however, HashMap has only one key to one value. So I intended to use 2 maps but this could not make use of composite key.

So are my thoughts correct? Or are there any better data collections in Java could be used in this case?

Thank for your time!

Comment: The key in a hashmap can be an object, so it could be an object containing both a and b.

Comment: You can use a HashMap<CompositeKey, Student>. Just make sure CompositeKey overrides equals() and hashCode() properly.

Comment: You can use a data-structure like `HashMap<String,HashMap<String,Integer>>`.

Comment: @SanketMakani That would work, but it'd be very easy to get lost and make mistakes.

Comment: What is a HashMap<CompositeKey, Student> ? Does it mean that I should create key1 and key2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no off the shelf data structure in Java for your need. There are multi valued map implementations in Apache Commons and Google Guava Collections but not in core Java.

But , In my opinion, you can implement it with a map declaration like - `Map<String, List<String>>` or `Map<String, List<Student>>` depending on whether you are keeping your student details as concatenated strings or as a `Student` class.

**While populating the map** - you will make two entries in map for first row / student , once for `a` and another entry for `a+b` concatenated.

Then while making entries for subsequent rows , you should first check if key exists in map or not, if it exists, you get the value , append new value and store again.

Record `a=Tom, b=school A, c=1402` will have two entries then comes record `a=Tom, b=school B, c=1403` and you will append record for key = `Tom` and add a new entry for `TomschoolB` so in total three entries in map for keys - `Tom` , `TomschoolA` and `TomschoolB`. Key `Tom` will have two items in value list while rest two will have single items.

Your lookup code should follow key calculation logic as key creation logic i.e. string concatenation or any other things as you wish.

This is just give a rough idea that multiple values can be handled via list.

**Edit :** From your comments, you look confused so below is code to implement the idea. You can tweak and extend it as you wish.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class MultiValuedMap {


    private static Map<String,List<String>> storage = new HashMap<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        store("Tom","Tom,schoolA,1402");
        store("TomschoolA","Tom,schoolA,1402");
        store("Tom","Tom,schoolB,1402");
        store("TomschoolB","Tom,schoolB,1403");

        storage.forEach((key,value) -> System.out.println("key:"+key+",value:"+value));

    }

    private static void store(String key, String value){

        if(storage.containsKey(key)) {
            List<String> newList = storage.get(key);
            newList.add(value);
            storage.put(key,newList);
        }else{
            List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
            values.add(value);
            storage.put(key,values);
        }

    }

}
```

**Output:**

```
key:Tom,value:[Tom,schoolA,1402, Tom,schoolB,1402]
key:TomschoolB,value:[Tom,schoolB,1403]
key:TomschoolA,value:[Tom,schoolA,1402]
```

Comment: Then I would have to create many lists, and I cannot find a way to do it. For example, I now check if the key"Tom" exists first. If it does not exist, I create a new list. But if other students' names are entered , new lists should be created. How to create those lists then?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Its going to be an `if - else` block. if key exists, append to existing list for the key else create a new list and store in map for that key in else block.

Comment: well , if I have 50 students, then i will need 50 lists.... how to create so many lists, I think it is dynamically

Comment: Thx a lot for your code! However, it always returns with a NullPointerException at the line containsKey.

Comment: Are you running my code or your own? if there is NPE at that line that means map object is null which is not the case for the code that I shared. I pasted program output too.

Comment: i am running my own code and i don't think there is much difference. So what can i do for a NPE?

Answer (score 0):

When you feel ambiguous of using any existing datastructure I suggest you to create your own data structure.With that you can create any methods and anything according to your need.

Comment: well, i created one with two maps connected but it does not work well. Probably i need to work on that more